# Sample Database of Tour Websites

Tags: database

so the problem is this, I need a sample database to create a tourist website !! I've searched on google but it does not match the keyword !! does anyone have an example of that database? please include the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a data model of database,using this model create you database

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/travel_agencies/index.htm